# Solving nonlinear eigenvalue problem with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I have an eigenvalue problem in the form

[image: formula]

At the moment I'm using `scipy.linalg.eig`. The strategy I use is conceptually similar to the [Campbel diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell_diagram) used to identify the natural frequencies of a rotor whose stiffness and damping are function of the rotating velocity. This is:

1. vary the value of [image: lambda_1] that I use to compute [image: A(l)] from 0 to a certain maximum value (or loop to infinity)
2. Compute the eigenvalues of [image: A(l)] for each value of [image: lambda_1]
3. Now for each eigenvalue (eg. the lowest one) "intersect" the function [image: l(l_1)] with the bisector [image: l=l_1]
4. Search for the intersection where the eigenvalue is equal to the value of [image: l] used to compute the matrix. Store it and the associated eigenvector.

This however is slow, tedious and, most importantly, it is required to "follow" the eigenvalues when [image] changes. When two eigenvalues "swap" order (the second becomes the third for example), you need to properly identify this to avoid errors.

Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_eigenproblem I'd look up references in the Wikipedia: some people wrote whole PhD theses about it!